# Net gear Nighthawk 5GHz not working while 2.4ghz still works

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a netgear nighthawk it was working fine until a month ago the 5GHz pops up and seems to be up and running but nothing can connect to it? Everything is currently running on 2.4ghz
I’ve rebooted I’ve factory reset I’ve searched online but I have NO IDEA what seems to be the problem

Comment: Do you use the official app on your phone? I have the app from https://www.netgear.com/support/product/netgear-mobile-app, and in there, there's a Settings → WiFi → WiFi Profiles section which is responsible for the 2.4 GHz / 5 GHz or Dual-Band setting. I wonder where the checkbox is set in your case. Sorry if you've already tried this, and it seems like simple advice, but I had a similar issue, and the app was the proper way to configure it. Cheers!

Comment: http://192.168.1.1/index.html#settings/profiles "(*) Dual band Wifi" - maybe not set so.